# I am trying to webscrape. The problem is that both have same class and tags, How to segregate using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape http://www.intermediary.natwest.com/intermediary-solutions/lending-criteria.html segregating in 2 parts Heading and Content, The problem is that both have same class and tags. Other than using regex and hard coding, How to distinguish and extract into 2 parts?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMmm.png)

In the picture or in the website link provided, Bold represents Heading and explanation(non-bold just below bold) represents the content.

The output looks something like this(Without Blanks)

[The Xlsx output File looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMmm.png)

Comment: You have to be a little more specific. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, nor what exactly what you are referring to as Heading and Content

Comment: The bold represents the heading and the explanation represents content(See Image), I have to store them in two different columns in an excel. How do you distinguish?

Comment: ah ok. That helps. Thanks.

Comment: How would the account look? You say two parts but there are multiple bold (headers?) with content.

Comment: Is A a header or is Age requirements or are both?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, No A is not the header, The output Looks like the xlsx image put in question https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMmm.png

Answer (score 0):

Convert each "section" to string, then split on the `<strong>` tags, essentially breaking it into a heading and content:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.intermediary.natwest.com/intermediary-solutions/lending-criteria.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

sections = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'accordion-section-content'})

results = {}
for section in sections:
    splits = section.prettify().split('<strong>')
    for each in splits:
        try:
            headline, content = each.split('</strong>')[0].strip(), each.split('</strong>')[1]
            headline = BeautifulSoup(headline, 'html.parser').text.strip()
            content = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser').text.strip()

            content_split = content.split('\n')
            content = ' '.join([ text.strip() for text in content_split if text != ''])

            results[headline] = content
        except:
            continue

df = pd.DataFrame(results.items(), columns = ['Headings','Content'])
df.to_csv('C:/test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But your code is not continuous as you can see, It's not extracting consecutive headline, 2. There are <p> and <ul>tags in between the <span> which will get lost.

Comment: The output looks something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMmm.png

Comment: @PavanSN, new solution above

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try this On a totally different note for the same question do you have any idea for this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807528/what-is-the-format-to-subtract-g-string-position-value-so-that-i-could-go-bac

Comment: I saw that question. I'm not quite understanding what you are asking or trying to do. Just also as a FYI, it would be beneficial to provide code that replicates the issue you are having, as people don't want to code out your issues. Ie: "this code produces <this> output., But I am trying to produce <that> output."

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Now i have modified it. Can you have a look

Comment: @PavanSN, you still haven't provided the full code though to create that output you say you are getting.